# MAMP Pro 3 "The installation failed."

Tags: installation, localhost, mamp, failed-installation, mamp-pro

I have just purchased an upgrade to MAMP Pro 3, downloaded the file (
MAMP_MAMP_PRO_3.0.5.pkg) and continued on to the Install. Unfortunately after three attempts I'm unable to complete the instal, the files are written and at the end I get an error msg:

> **The installation failed.** The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for
>   assistance.

(need to work on my reputation before I can post a screen grab unfortunately)

Has anyone else had this issue? and how did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was raised some time ago, but I faced the same problem days ago where I could not install MAMP on my Mac and the "Installation Failed" got me nervous.

It turned out the file I had downloaded was corrupted. I downloaded it again and this time I checked its SHA-1 checksum to assure it was the same as in the website. Indeed, it was and the installation therefore went smoothly.

To check checksums on Windows, I used the File Checksum Integrity Verifier which can be downloaded from Microsoft (tiny file).
For Mac, there are commands to run in the console. I don't have them at hand, otherwise I'd add them here.