# MAMP 5.5 Installation failed in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mamp, macos-catalina, mamp-pro

[image]

Before upgrading to Mac OS Catalina. MAMP was working fine. After upgrading it to Mac OS Catalina, MAMP 5.5 stopped working. So I decided to uninstall and re-install. But When I tried to install it (fresh), The installation fails. Please somebody guide me to resolve this. Thank You.

Comment: Why not using the new version `5.6` is there something wrong with `5.6` preventing you from using it?

Comment: Tried with 5.6 too. Still I am getting the same error

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402170/mamp-pro-3-the-installation-failed

Comment: And also take a look at this -> https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215197426-My-MAMP-PRO-installer-did-not-work-

Comment: I have the same problem. It is the first time I installed MAMP, and showed same error above. Tried restart mac, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific for your pc and we don't have as much info as we would like.
You have to check these settings that thay mention on their [docs](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Installation/) before installing and follow their guide.

If that seems frustrating, i would suggest to use [bitnami mamp](https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp/installer) that solves issues regarding the enviroments

Answer (score 0):

Too few information to identify the problem, some suggestion you could try
1. Check if the software is fully uninstall, some software often remain some package or config
2. Using another server stack like Wamp, xamp, ampp ...